# Add predicted array to trained array

Tags: java, android

I need to add the predictedData array to the array above for training.

The fifth value in the predictedData is going to be predicted.

```
public void machineLearning() throws Exception {
        Object[][] weatherData = new Object[][]{
                {0, 27, 60, 17, 7}, {7, 26, 68, 17, 30},
                {30, 27, 57, 14, 14}, {14, 24, 73, 13, 30},
                {30, 26, 64, 18, 20}, {20, 27, 62, 17, 18},
                {18, 27, 63, 12, 18}, {18, 26, 70, 15, 46},
                {46, 26, 66, 18, 33}, {33, 27, 62, 21, 22},
                {22, 27, 64, 16, 29}, {29, 26, 62, 15, 23},
                {23, 25, 66, 17, 34}, {34, 28, 53, 13, 9},
                {9, 28, 66, 18, 10}, {10, 25, 74, 18, 27},
                {27, 27, 68, 19, 12}, {12, 26, 70, 12, 29},
                {29, 24, 78, 19, 40}, {40, 26, 63, 25, 10},
                {10, 25, 66, 18, 18}, {18, 26, 69, 15, 17},
                {17, 24, 76, 15, 25}, {25, 24, 80, 11, 31}
        };

        NeuralNet neuralNetwork = new NeuralNet();   //Call the NeuralNetwork class
        neuralNetwork.readAndTrain(weatherData);     //Read and train the data given in weatherDate object
        neuralNetwork.setupNeuralNet();

        //Data to predict
        Object[][] predictData = new Object[][]{
                {30, 27, 70, 18}
        };

        //System.out.println("The new Value is " + neuralNetwork.predictStyle(predictData));
        machineTxt.setText(String.valueOf(neuralNetwork.predictStyle(predictData)));
    }
```

Comment: So where's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method that will grow the array:

```
private static Object[][] addData(Object[][] prevData, Object[][] newData) {

    int prevDataCount = prevData.length;

    Object[][] resultData = new Object[prevDataCount + 1][];
    System.arraycopy(prevData, 0, resultData, 0, prevData.length);
    resultData[prevDataCount] = newData[0];

    return resultData;
}
```

Then call it like that:

```
Object[][] withPrediction = addData( weatherData, predictData);
```

But if you know your arrays will grow you may consider unsing another data structure that allow expansion such as ArrayLists.